# What could cause no pain but sense of touch?

Tags: neuroscience, touch

What could cause a mammal to have and respond to a sense of touch with only isolated numbness but not feel pain?

Comment: [CIPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_insensitivity_to_pain_with_anhidrosis)?

Comment: Loss of nociceptive pathways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Congenital insensitivity to pain with anhidrosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_insensitivity_to_pain_with_anhidrosis) might be what you are looking for, it is the closest thing I can think of right now.